# Serializing and deserializing a collection of objects

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm trying to create an Rssfeed reader which saves info about a podcast to a JSON file and I'm having trouble serializing and deserializing to that file.

I realize that there are other threads regarding this subject, but I cannot grasp or comprehend how to apply it to my code or the reasoning behind it.

So I have a bit of code that creates a file if it doesn't exist and writes JSON data to it which looks like:

```
public void SaveFile(Podcast podcast)
{
    try
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

        if(!File.Exists(@"C: \Users\Kasper\Desktop\Projektuppgift\Projektuppgift - Delkurs2\Projektet\Projektet\bin\Debug\podcasts.json"))
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new { Podcast = podcast });
            StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"C:\Users\Kasper\Desktop\Projektuppgift\Projektuppgift-Delkurs2\Projektet\Projektet\bin\Debug\podcasts.json");
            using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, json);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var filepath = @"C:\Users\Kasper\Desktop\Projektuppgift\Projektuppgift-Delkurs2\Projektet\Projektet\bin\Debug\podcasts.json";
            var jsonData = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
            var podcasts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Podcast>>(jsonData) ?? new List<Podcast>();
            podcasts.Add(podcast);
            jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {PodcastList = podcasts });
            File.WriteAllText(filepath, jsonData);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IO Exception ", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

What I can't get to work is to deserialize from this file and add an object to it. Is there an easier way to add more data to the JSON file or am I missing something?

The `Podcast` class looks like this:

```
public class Podcast
{
    public string url { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public int updateInterval { get; set; }

    public string category { get; set; }
    //public Category category = new Category();

    public List<Episode> episodes { get; set; }

    public Podcast(string url, string name, Category category, List<Episode> episodes, int updateInterval)
    {
        this.url = url;
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category.name;
        this.episodes = episodes;
        this.updateInterval = updateInterval;
    }

    public Podcast(Podcast p)
    {
        this.url = p.url;
        this.name = p.name;
        this.category = p.category;
        this.episodes = p.episodes;
        this.updateInterval = p.updateInterval;
    }
}
```

Comment: `new { Podcast = podcast })` -- you probably want to create a new `List<Podcast>` there, not a new anonymous object with a single `Podcast` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appear to be a couple of issues here:

1. You are checking for the existence of a different file than the one you are reading/writing.  The former filename has extra spaces in it.  The best way to avoid this problem is to use a variable to contain the filename rather than hardcoding it in three separate places.
2. You are inconsistent about the JSON format you are writing and reading:

   - When you first create the file (in the first branch), you are writing a JSON object that contains a property `Podcast` which then contains a single podcast.
   - When you attempt to read the JSON file, you are treating the entire JSON as a list of podcasts.
   - After tacking the new podcast onto the list, you are writing the JSON as a single object containing a `PodcastList` property, which then contains the list.

You need to use a consistent JSON format.  I would recommend breaking your code into smaller methods to read and write the `podcasts.json` file like this so that it is easier to reason about:

```
public static List<Podcast> ReadPodcastsFromFile(string filepath)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filepath)) return new List<Podcast>();

    string json = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Podcast>>(json);
}

public static void WritePodcastsToFile(List<Podcast> podcasts, string filepath)
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(podcasts);
    // This will overwrite the file if it exists, or create a new one if it doesn't
    File.WriteAllText(filepath, json);
}
```

Then, you can simplify your `SaveFile` method down to this (I would be tempted to rename it to `SavePodcast`):

```
public void SaveFile(Podcast podcast)
{
    var filepath = @"C:\Users\Kasper\Desktop\Projektuppgift\Projektuppgift-Delkurs2\Projektet\Projektet\bin\Debug\podcasts.json";
    List<Podcast> podcasts = ReadPodcastsFromFile(filepath);
    podcasts.Add(podcast);
    WritePodcastsToFile(podcasts, filepath);
}
```

Notice I've also removed the exception handling from `SaveFile`.  You should move that up to wherever `SaveFile` is called, so that you can take appropriate action at that point if an exception is thrown, e.g.:

```
try
{
    SaveFile(podcast);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Show a message to the user indicating that the file did not save
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just still learning c# but it might be that you deserialise into a list of podcasts and when you serialise you're serliasing into an object type.

Comment: How would you then serialize to a list of podcasts? Or would you serialize it in another way?

Comment: tbh i don't know the times i use json serialise i usually use their attributes/label my data so it helps with mappping, try to check out attrinbutes in json